# Objective C: Filter out results from NSMutableArray by a dictionary key's value?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, xcode4.5

I have a NSMutableArray like this :

```
(
        {
        City = "Orlando";
       Name = "Shoreline Dental";
        State = Florida;
    },
        {
        City = "Alabaster ";
        Name = Oxford Multispeciality;
        State = Alabama;
    },
        {
        City = Dallas;
        Name = "Williams Spa";
        State = Texas;
    },
        {
        City = "Orlando ";
        Name = "Roast Street";
        State = Florida;
    }
)
```

Now how can I sort this NSMutableArray to get the results corresponding to State "Florida"
I expect to get

```
(
        {
        City = "Orlando";
       Name = "Shoreline Dental";
        State = Florida;
    },
 {
        City = "Orlando ";
        Name = "Roast Street";
        State = Florida;
    }
)
```

I went for this code,but it displays again the prevous four dictionaries .

```
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Florida" ascending:YES];
       NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];
        NSArray * sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: You don't really want to sort the array, but retrieve a subarray, right?

Comment: are city,name,state are properties of an object? or directly in an array?

Comment: directly in array.I have retrieved the array from service url

Comment: @AnoopVaidya obviously this is the description of an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a comparator block:

```
NSIndexSet *indices = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"State"] isEqualToString:@"Florida"];
}];
NSArray *filtered = [array objectsAtIndexes:indices];
```

Alternatively, you can use a predicate as well:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"State = %@", @"Florida"];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

Comment: Alternative answer is not working, I am not able to find the bug :(

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Cool. (I wouldn't have thought that such an inconsistency exists in Foundation, but well, for some extent, it's logical...)

Comment: @H2CO3: On a lighter note, Anoop Vaidya got alternative answer correct 4 seconds earlier than you :) :) +1 for your answer :)

Comment: @ParthBhatt Thanks. Well, I don't always refresh the page/click on "Load new answers"...

Comment: @H2CO3: Yes I understand.. Even I don't do "Load new answers" :)

Answer (score 2):

If your array contains dictionary then you can use NSPredicate to filter out your array as follows:

```
NSPredicate *thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"State CONTAINS[cd] Florida"];
theFilteredArray = [theArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:thePredicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array name is : `arr`

This one of the typical way to find, although a bit obsolete way....

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"State"]isEqualToString:@"Florida"]) {
        [filteredArray addObject:dict];
    }
}
NSLog(@"filteredArray->%@",filteredArray);
```

Using predicates and blocks are already posted :)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"State = %@", @"Florida"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filtered ->%@",filteredArray);
```